# props can not be resolved in the render of a React class

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am getting started on webdevelopment with React and Node.js, all are new to me so I am following this tutorial: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html. I am using Visual Studio as IDE.

Everything seems to go as expected until I try to pass data through props. At that point "props" becomes flagged with an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'props'. I have googled myself silly trying to find a solution.

So far I have tried:

- import React instead of declaring it as variable. Gives another error: Symbol 'React' cannot be properly resolved, probably it is located in inaccessible module
- create a constructor. Gives another error: Call target does not contain any signatures.
- Installed npm package for prop-types
- I have posted my question to the relevant discord

So at this point I turn to you all, can you help me get going? See my code below:

```
declare var require: any;

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
//import * as React from "react";
//import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";


//node_modules\.bin\webpack app.tsx --config webpack-config.js
class Square extends React.Component<any, any> {
    //constructor() {
    //    super();
    //}

    render() { 
        return (
            <button className="square">
                {this.props.value}
            </button>
        );
    }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
    renderSquare(i) {
        return <Square value={i}/>;
    }

    render() {
        const status = 'Next player: X';

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="status">{status}</div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(0)}
                    {this.renderSquare(1)}
                    {this.renderSquare(2)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(3)}
                    {this.renderSquare(4)}
                    {this.renderSquare(5)}
                </div>
                <div className="board-row">
                    {this.renderSquare(6)}
                    {this.renderSquare(7)}
                    {this.renderSquare(8)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="game">
                <div className="game-board">
                    <Board />
                </div>
                <div className="game-info">
                    <div>{/* status */}</div>
                    <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
    <Game />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: How are you passing the prop data? I just tried your example. seems to work. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-wsackq

Comment: It's exactly as posted above. It seems I am missing a reference or something in Visual Studio is mucking up my environment... I really do not get it...